# How Can I Heal/Prevent Jumper's (Patellar Tendinitis) Knee?

Tags: injury, knees, injury-prevention, tendons

About me: 
29 years old
170 lbs
Active (mountain biking, skiing, basketball)

In the last year or so I've started to develop symptoms of what I think is Jumper's Knee (pain right beneath the kneecap that gets worse with more activity).

I know rest is probably the most logical "treatment", but the pain isn't bad enough to completely stop me from staying active. And also, I have gone through rest periods only to have the issue resurface rather quickly.

Right now I have been doing the following:

(a) taking a glucosamine/chondroitin supplement 
(b) massaging the area just below the kneecap before physical activity

Anything else I should/could be doing?

Comment: I'd tend to guess you didn't rest quite long enough. If you are really needing to get back into the game, there are [cortisone shots](http://www.medicinenet.com/cortisone_injection/article.htm). If you are juicing, [deca durabolin](http://www.isteroids.com/steroids/Deca-Durabolin.html) is an excellent lubrication.

Comment: @Ben decline squats worked for me, and are supported by data: https://bjsm.bmj.com/content/39/2/102

Answer (score 0):

For relief during exercise, you can get a knee band:
[Rehband Knee Strap](http://www.rehband.com/7757-knee-strap-rehband.html)
For actually treating the symptoms get a foam roller and roll your IT band.  Foam roll, stretch, ice and take an anti-inflammatory (ibuprofen and omega-3s).  These things combined should help you out.

Comment: I'll look into the roller thing. Hadn't heard of that previously.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go to a sports doctor esp. since it's better to catch this while you're young and regenerate faster than when you're older. I had this piercing pain on my left knee when it wasn't moving. It usually happened while I was driving; I guess the certain angle I had it at in the car aggravated it.

I went to a sports doc who did an X-ray and I was diagnosed with [chondromalacia](http://www.arthritis-treatment-and-relief.com/chondromalacia-exercises.html) (which has the same symptoms as jumper's knee, runner's knee, tennis knee, hiker's knee --- basically overuse of a repetitive motion). I played volleyball and had terrible form then. I would jump on the one knee to spike rather than both legs.

"Chondromalacia is caused by the disproportionate development of muscles around the knee. The muscles then pull the knee cap in an abnormal direction (ref: above link)" So you want to focus on strengthening the muscle that is weaker which is why I suggest going to a doctor to find out the real underlying issue and if it's chondromalacia, to see which muscle is weaker (you can tell because your knee cap will be angled and you need to "get" it straight).

Good luck!

Comment: If it continues to bother me, I will definitely go see someone once my insurance kicks in (new job). Hmm, I wonder if this could be related to the relatively extreme amount of mountain biking I did this past season. My quads are definitely a lot bigger than they were before I started. Maybe my hamstrings aren't proportionally strong or something.

Answer (score 0):

**This is maybe the most important question on this site!** (For runners, volleyball players, basketball players, jumpers etc. etc.) Thank you for this.

I was fighting with my Jumper's knee for 2 years. Why I experienced this? 5 volleyball amateur trainings per week (too young and too eager!) + no special supplementation + no coach + no compensation exercise. I was even thinking about giving up this beautiful sport. What's now? I'm jumping without any support and playing again at full blast!

How to get rid of it in initial phase or prevent it? The key is your quadriceps femoris muscle. You need to exercise and strengthen it **EVERY SINGLE DAY!**

See this video from 1:45 the first exercise -- slightly rotated leg lifting. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHNqaPrCpvY

You can do it while waiting on the bus stop (while standing), you can do it in your work while sitting, you can do it whenever and anywhere you want to and anyone don't tell me that you can't!

Only this one worked for me. I wish you good luck. I hope you will catch it in the initial phase and cure it totally.